# EmberJS - Manually bind controller to view

Tags: binding, ember.js, requirejs

Lately EmberJS changed a lot (Router, ...) and the code I have started to write less than a month ago is now broken.
One of the issue I have right now is I am not able to manually bind the controller to the view.

I am using requireJS by the way...

So I used to the able to do something like this (here to define the view for my menu and the menu items), to actually get the Controller content and selected properties.

```
define
(
    'app/common/views/menu',
    [
        'text!app/common/templates/menu.hbs',
        'ember'
    ],
    /**
     * Menu view
     *
     * @param template
     * @returns Class
     */
    function( template )
    {
        return Ember.View.extend
        ({
            controllerBinding : 'controller.controllers.menuController',
            selectedBinding: 'controller.selected',
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile( template ),
            NavItemView: Ember.View.extend
            ({
                tagName: 'li',
                classNameBindings: 'isActive:active'.w(),
                isActive: function()
                {
                    return this.get('item') === this.get('parentView.selected');
                }.property('item', 'parentView.selected').cacheable()
            })
        })
    }
);
```

It looks like 'controller.controllers.menuController' doesn't exists anymore.
I have been able to find the class in the container cache 'container.cache.contoller:menu' but my view controller will still be null.
I have also try `App.MenuController` being defined in the `Application.create({})`

Any idea?

On a side note, if anybody has a working example using the latest (github) EmberJS and requireJS I would be VERY interested :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the latest TODOMVC Ember/require.js! :D I'll come back to answer your questions more explicitly:

https://github.com/sh4n3d4v15/ember-todos

Comment: Hello Shane. Thx for the answer. I have seen the (yours?) project on gthub but sadly i am on windows at work and it looks like yeoman is not yet available on it... Also i discovered grunt and yeoman looking at the project and i have one question regarding this. The string takes all the js files in the app folder and expand them in the main

Comment: Its not mine originally, it was from https://github.com/tzellman/ember-todos . Yeah, It basically performs a string replacement and adds all the files in.  I you mark this answer as correct so others know its the correct approach, I am working on a non yeoman version that I'll add the link to and will be a lot more accesable :)

Comment: Sorry posted the comment too early (typing from my phone). Full comment below

Comment: Hello Shane. Thx for the answer. I have seen the (yours?) project on gthub but sadly i am on windows at work and it looks like yeoman is not yet available on it... Also i discovered grunt and yeoman looking at the project and i have one question regarding this. The string takes all the js files in the app folder and add their path into the require definition in the main.js. So it means that all the js are required on load am i correct? You are using requirejs to structure your app but not to do a modular application... Looking forward to reading your answer. Thx heaps!

Comment: Hiya, zeflasher, the compiled main.js will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sh4n3/GwTVs/

Comment: Thx again, I have been able to get my app working now.
I will post a sample on github for you and any people who would like to have a look. I will update the question with a link to github once done (tomorrow). Thx again

Comment: Hey Shane, just in case, I have another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349347/emberjs-requirejs-how-to-initialize-view-and-controllers-and-display-them-af related to EmberJS. Have created a github project with the application. If you mind checking... Thx heaps